# Are the funnel urls specified when configuring Google Analytic goals accepting url parameters as default?

Tags: google-analytics, goal-tracking

I've setup a goal which uses a funnel.   For the page that the user has to go to first, which GA calls the "Screen/Page" I've nevered the url of that page, ie

/page-name/

But what about if someone accesses this page with a url parameter?, ie

/page-name?param1=b

Is that going to get included in my funnel ?   Does this funnel url accept regex / wildcards ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The matching of pages in the funnel will use whatever match behavior you selected for the destination page. So if you put "Begins with" for the destination, then the funnel will also use Begins With matching.

If you want to use regex, then, you can do so by setting the initial match to "Regular expression".

This was a tricky one! The answer came from Google's [Destination Goal Examples](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1116091?hl=en) page, which is the best reference I've found for goal funnels.